# Inconsistent hash result

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I'm working on a basic Python 3 authentication system with passwords and optional usernames. Here's the segment I have:

```
import hashlib
import os.path
from secure import BadCharacterError


def setLayers(filePath, passwords, usernames=None):
    # sanity check
    if os.path.exists(filePath): raise FileExistsError
    if usernames is not None and len(usernames) != len(passwords): raise IndexError
    for name in usernames:
        if "|" in name: raise BadCharacterError("Username contained bad character '|'!")

    # Hash the passwords
    counter = 0
    for password in passwords:
        salt = ""
        if usernames is not None: salt = hashlib.sha512(usernames[counter].encode()).hexdigest()  # generate a salt
        hashedPassword = hashlib.sha512(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest()  # hash them together
        passwords[counter] = hashedPassword  # replace the list entry
        counter += 1

    # write them to a file
    with open(filePath, "a+") as file:
        counter = 0
        for password in passwords:
            if usernames is None:
                file.write(password)
            else:
                file.write(password + "|" + usernames[counter] + "\n")
            counter += 1


def checkLayer(filePath, password, username=None):
    # sanity check
    if not os.path.exists(filePath): raise FileNotFoundError

    # find the password hash
    salt = ""
    if username is not None: salt = hashlib.sha512(username.encode()).hexdigest()  # find the salt
    hashedPassword = hashlib.sha512(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest()  # hash them together

    with open(filePath, "r") as file:
        db = file.read().split("\n")
        counter = 0
        if username is not None:
            for entry in db:
                entry = entry.split("|")
                dbPassword = entry[0]
                dbUsername = entry[1]
                if dbPassword == hashedPassword and dbUsername == username:
                    return counter
                counter += 1
        elif username is None:
            for entry in db:
                if hashedPassword == entry:
                    return counter
                counter += 1

        return False  # we will only reach this point if all of the others were not matched
```

I have a test program that will run first `setLayers()` and then `checkLayer` with appropriate parameters that should cause a match in `checkLayer()`. However, it always returns False (instead of a number, which would happen if there was a match).

Debugging to find the comparisons being made shows this:

```
ae7d239aca090e393d5a70620130746ea3f8decc131318739df7097741f2b9ad9fe3679cc1f48a9bd1649f2c3e7c9c279adae116511e7397d0ec16ef59803ec9 User1
76a92b70d005bf3d7ae31e7506df098ca0bf00c0f701a54de84f23a11095ca9832b00cd9ae4ce02867600c8e5e2a144ecfce059c22e9ea2070bf80883c6616db User2

0838b3c1856b32c2b84c6ab1b1770935588d348123c8439d9546f0829a7cd52a8696f927fbf0ae5b1dbc4be0e15e1da3b3e240974db7b6954f30b87acadccc42 User2
76a92b70d005bf3d7ae31e7506df098ca0bf00c0f701a54de84f23a11095ca9832b00cd9ae4ce02867600c8e5e2a144ecfce059c22e9ea2070bf80883c6616db User2

703bce701812f2cd00476c455d9d56df21b1e8f7c3dab5cef2e50e407f6b06733f1d771a60162d4380320cc498e3dc6143dd94bec31377086c526d8fbd3ec9ac User3
76a92b70d005bf3d7ae31e7506df098ca0bf00c0f701a54de84f23a11095ca9832b00cd9ae4ce02867600c8e5e2a144ecfce059c22e9ea2070bf80883c6616db User2
```

Each group of two lines is separated by a line. The first line in the group is the stored password/username set, while the second is the one entered into `checkLine()`. The second group from the top should have matching hashes.

Why is this not the case, and how can I solve it?

Thanks.